# geometries node screw, spiral

Tags: geometry-nodes

Made a geometry nodes screw generator it's not finished yet.
The goal is to be able to 3d print screws that actually work (with offset) between screw and bolt.

Well, the setup is quite complex I'll show a picture and include the blend file.
What I need is that the threads, at the end (and start) don't end with a flat surface, but with a cone point (narrowing) over last/first x circle instances.   Because if a screw would end as in the picture it's not possible to put a bold on it.  any ideas for this ?.

[image]

file located on blend-exchange.
Please if you want to provide an answer use it as well.
As they have a don't delete ever policy.
[image]

problem in detail:
[image]

Comment: This is off topic but you may be able to compare and pull standards from the bolt Factory plugin https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/add_mesh/boltfactory.html

Answer (score 2):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Hint: you should try to structure your node tree with e.g. group nodes, frames, positioning of nodes, labeling of frames/nodes

Comment: can you drop the blend file on it ?

Answer (score 1):

Forgive me if this doesn't apply in your case, but personally I think it's a good idea to break GN trees up into sub-groups, representing semantically separable, and (at least conceivably) re-usable components. Even if the groups never get re-used, it means you can debug and test them separately, and share them more economically. If they're well-named, they can make a tree more readable. You can also put soft limits on  parameters, sanitizing inputs as far as possible.

In this case, you might pull out the 'Taper Curve Ends' operation in some way like this..

[image]

... and use it in some way like this...

[image]

...(making no claim this is the best way for you)... with a result like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes organizing is a next step indeed i should do that, it becomes hard otherwise to keep track of it all. although its a bity complex it kinda works all together.

Comment: @Peter  Well, I find it hard to read/illustrate even moderately large GN trees on BSE.. I hope  GN Q&A's tend towards smaller modular groups, as we evolve.. :)